# Custom ImageDataGenerator misbehaves

Tags: python, keras

I wrote a custom Keras ImageDataGenerator: to load images from disk. The logic is: in an infinite cycle, init the batch with random values from arrays of file names, load those files and that's all.

The problem seems to be in the "init" part. I used file to dump resulting file names, and discovered that they are always the same, as if randint was returning same array every time. Any ideas what I missed?

First I quote the code, then the file it produced.

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
rotation_range=30,
width_shift_range=0.2,
height_shift_range=0.2,
zoom_range=0.2)

def image_generator(image_file_names, labels):
    i = 0
    while True:
        arr_idx = np.random.randint(len(image_file_names), size = BATCH_SIZE)
        batch_file_names = image_file_names[arr_idx]
        batch_labels = labels[arr_idx]

        text_file = open("log1.txt", "a")
        text_file.write("\n".join(batch_file_names))
        text_file.write("\n%s===================\n" % i)
        i = i + 1
        text_file.close()

        batch_images = []

        for input_path in batch_file_names:
            img = load_img("../input/train/" + input_path,
                target_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE), grayscale=True)
             img = img_to_array(img)
             img = datagen.random_transform(img, seed=42)
             img = img / 255.
             batch_images += [img]

        batch_images = np.array(batch_images)

        yield(batch_images, batch_labels)


d5896c9a0.jpg
d0c025463.jpg
a94abfec3.jpg
93d091bc1.jpg
0706d4216.jpg
2949b6643.jpg
545874c14.jpg
c04b414b2.jpg
ccfd02948.jpg
7be9c59f8.jpg
c74822baf.jpg
74e611f3c.jpg
c7a2fd5e2.jpg
a9269fb58.jpg
b81462e5b.jpg
88285e65a.jpg
0
===================
d5896c9a0.jpg
d0c025463.jpg
a94abfec3.jpg
93d091bc1.jpg
0706d4216.jpg
2949b6643.jpg
545874c14.jpg
c04b414b2.jpg
ccfd02948.jpg
7be9c59f8.jpg
c74822baf.jpg
74e611f3c.jpg
c7a2fd5e2.jpg
a9269fb58.jpg
b81462e5b.jpg
88285e65a.jpg
0
===================
d5896c9a0.jpg
d0c025463.jpg
a94abfec3.jpg
93d091bc1.jpg
0706d4216.jpg
2949b6643.jpg
545874c14.jpg
c04b414b2.jpg
ccfd02948.jpg
7be9c59f8.jpg
c74822baf.jpg
74e611f3c.jpg
c7a2fd5e2.jpg
a9269fb58.jpg
b81462e5b.jpg
88285e65a.jpg
0
===================
d5896c9a0.jpg
d0c025463.jpg
a94abfec3.jpg
93d091bc1.jpg
0706d4216.jpg
2949b6643.jpg
545874c14.jpg
c04b414b2.jpg
ccfd02948.jpg
7be9c59f8.jpg
c74822baf.jpg
74e611f3c.jpg
c7a2fd5e2.jpg
a9269fb58.jpg
b81462e5b.jpg
88285e65a.jpg
0
===================
d5896c9a0.jpg
d0c025463.jpg
a94abfec3.jpg
93d091bc1.jpg
0706d4216.jpg
2949b6643.jpg
545874c14.jpg
c04b414b2.jpg
ccfd02948.jpg
7be9c59f8.jpg
c74822baf.jpg
74e611f3c.jpg
c7a2fd5e2.jpg
a9269fb58.jpg
b81462e5b.jpg
88285e65a.jpg
0
===================
d5896c9a0.jpg
d0c025463.jpg
a94abfec3.jpg
93d091bc1.jpg
0706d4216.jpg
2949b6643.jpg
545874c14.jpg
c04b414b2.jpg
ccfd02948.jpg
7be9c59f8.jpg
c74822baf.jpg
74e611f3c.jpg
c7a2fd5e2.jpg
a9269fb58.jpg
b81462e5b.jpg
88285e65a.jpg
0
===================
d5896c9a0.jpg
d0c025463.jpg
a94abfec3.jpg
93d091bc1.jpg
0706d4216.jpg
2949b6643.jpg
545874c14.jpg
c04b414b2.jpg
ccfd02948.jpg
7be9c59f8.jpg
c74822baf.jpg
74e611f3c.jpg
c7a2fd5e2.jpg
a9269fb58.jpg
b81462e5b.jpg
88285e65a.jpg
0
===================
d5896c9a0.jpg
d0c025463.jpg
a94abfec3.jpg
93d091bc1.jpg
0706d4216.jpg
2949b6643.jpg
545874c14.jpg
c04b414b2.jpg
ccfd02948.jpg
7be9c59f8.jpg
c74822baf.jpg
74e611f3c.jpg
c7a2fd5e2.jpg
a9269fb58.jpg
b81462e5b.jpg
88285e65a.jpg
0
===================
b6f0ef08f.jpg
6132f858d.jpg
15db53751.jpg
f66a7c2a3.jpg
e12a65860.jpg
afc456dd3.jpg
439320f0c.jpg
82aab5924.jpg
a3fab7973.jpg
99ce90134.jpg
5fe14e4d0.jpg
e05e1a2e0.jpg
515d6eb11.jpg
b54652474.jpg
ee07a850c.jpg
b63842413.jpg
1
===================
b6f0ef08f.jpg
6132f858d.jpg
15db53751.jpg
f66a7c2a3.jpg
e12a65860.jpg
afc456dd3.jpg
439320f0c.jpg
82aab5924.jpg
a3fab7973.jpg
99ce90134.jpg
5fe14e4d0.jpg
e05e1a2e0.jpg
515d6eb11.jpg
b54652474.jpg
ee07a850c.jpg
b63842413.jpg
1
===================
b6f0ef08f.jpg
6132f858d.jpg
15db53751.jpg
f66a7c2a3.jpg
e12a65860.jpg
afc456dd3.jpg
439320f0c.jpg
82aab5924.jpg
a3fab7973.jpg
99ce90134.jpg
5fe14e4d0.jpg
e05e1a2e0.jpg
515d6eb11.jpg
b54652474.jpg
ee07a850c.jpg
b63842413.jpg
1
===================
b6f0ef08f.jpg
6132f858d.jpg
15db53751.jpg
f66a7c2a3.jpg
e12a65860.jpg
afc456dd3.jpg
439320f0c.jpg
82aab5924.jpg
a3fab7973.jpg
99ce90134.jpg
5fe14e4d0.jpg
e05e1a2e0.jpg
515d6eb11.jpg
b54652474.jpg
ee07a850c.jpg
b63842413.jpg
1
===================
b6f0ef08f.jpg
6132f858d.jpg
15db53751.jpg
f66a7c2a3.jpg
e12a65860.jpg
afc456dd3.jpg
439320f0c.jpg
82aab5924.jpg
a3fab7973.jpg
99ce90134.jpg
5fe14e4d0.jpg
e05e1a2e0.jpg
515d6eb11.jpg
b54652474.jpg
ee07a850c.jpg
b63842413.jpg
2
===================
b6f0ef08f.jpg
6132f858d.jpg
15db53751.jpg
f66a7c2a3.jpg
e12a65860.jpg
afc456dd3.jpg
439320f0c.jpg
82aab5924.jpg
a3fab7973.jpg
99ce90134.jpg
5fe14e4d0.jpg
e05e1a2e0.jpg
515d6eb11.jpg
b54652474.jpg
ee07a850c.jpg
b63842413.jpg
2
===================
b6f0ef08f.jpg
6132f858d.jpg
15db53751.jpg
f66a7c2a3.jpg
e12a65860.jpg
afc456dd3.jpg
439320f0c.jpg
82aab5924.jpg
a3fab7973.jpg
99ce90134.jpg
5fe14e4d0.jpg
e05e1a2e0.jpg
515d6eb11.jpg
b54652474.jpg
ee07a850c.jpg
b63842413.jpg
2
===================
b6f0ef08f.jpg
6132f858d.jpg
15db53751.jpg
f66a7c2a3.jpg
e12a65860.jpg
afc456dd3.jpg
439320f0c.jpg
82aab5924.jpg
a3fab7973.jpg
99ce90134.jpg
5fe14e4d0.jpg
e05e1a2e0.jpg
515d6eb11.jpg
b54652474.jpg
ee07a850c.jpg
b63842413.jpg
2
===================
b6f0ef08f.jpg
6132f858d.jpg
15db53751.jpg
f66a7c2a3.jpg
e12a65860.jpg
afc456dd3.jpg
439320f0c.jpg
82aab5924.jpg
a3fab7973.jpg
99ce90134.jpg
5fe14e4d0.jpg
e05e1a2e0.jpg
515d6eb11.jpg
b54652474.jpg
ee07a850c.jpg
b63842413.jpg
3
===================
b6f0ef08f.jpg
6132f858d.jpg
15db53751.jpg
```

Here is the code to call it:

```
history = model.fit_generator(image_generator(np_train[:, 0], train_labels), 
steps_per_epoch=len(np_train) / BATCH_SIZE, epochs=1,
validation_data=([x_valid[:,:,:, :1]], [valid_labels]), #class_weight=class_weights,
callbacks=[saveBestModel], use_multiprocessing=True, workers=4)
```

==========================

Edited: data that I feed to it.
Labels (printing two different samples):

```
print(train_labels[0], "\n", train_labels[CLASSES])
```

Result:

```
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.] 
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

Image file names:

```
np_train
```

Result:

```
array([['3d5c45078.jpg', 'w_23a388d'],
['3e53c9584.jpg', 'w_23a388d'],
['3e8b8d8d9.jpg', 'w_23a388d'],
...,
['dada37134.jpg', 'w_b938e96'],
['054bb95c0.jpg', 'w_b938e96'],
['19a81076c.jpg', 'w_b938e96']], dtype='<U13')
```

And I only feed the "images" column:

```
model.fit_generator(image_generator(np_train[:, 0], train_labels)
```

Labels are duplicated, so there can be

```
1.jpg    label_1
2.jpg    label_1
...
```

Now, look at

```
text_file.write("\n%s===================\n" % i)
```

part of a cycle. It writes a counter for a batch to file. Now, if you look at file content (above), you will see that batch number changes... one time per FIVE batches. 
Part of the problem is that I do not understand the way it should work, particularly, the "while True" part. From the point of view of "normal" programming, it is an infinite cycle, so how comers it does not hung up the program?

Comment: I guess this is depending on your `batch_file_names` variable. Can you show how you generate that one?

Comment: Edited, to show the input data.

Comment: Did you check the output of the randint?
Small side note: if you want to have each image only once in a batch, use sth different, eg. `np.random.permutation(len(image_file_names))[:BATCH_SIZE]`.

Comment: See, part of the problem is, I don't quite understand how it is supposed to work. Particularly, I do not understand the idea behind "while True". From "normal" programming point of view, it is an infinite cycle, so how comes that it does not hung up the program? I have altered the code (above) to count batches. Resulta (again, added to main post) are very strange: it seems that each time we enter "while", we get FIVE batches! No idea why.

Comment: This depends on how often this generator gets called. See [this article](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) for more explanation on generators.

Generators always stop on `yield` and return the values before proceeding. So everytime this function is called, it returns sth. Defining `while True` means that there will never be a end in the generation of batches.

Comment: Ok, got this part. But it should get random batches, right? And it changes only once, instead of getting new indexes in each batch.

Comment: Thats true. Did you somehow fix the random seed?

Comment: No, as I don't need each image only once. Is something wrong with randint?

Comment: No I dont think so. To make sure, use the generator in a for loop and try to debug: `for imgs, labels in generator(...)`.  Print out all the random generated indices for shuffling. S oyou have a standalone version without all the keras stuff.

Comment: Is the inner structure of a "while" cycle correct? Like the overall logic of getting an array outside the inner cycle and so on?

Comment: As far as I can observe now, yes. But now it's your turn to start debugging!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem with data generation was due to "use_multiprocessing=True, workers=4": when removed, the chaotic behavior stopped.